# AngularJS Won't Recognize Multiple Controllers in Single HTML File

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I'm finding a weird instance where I am trying to use multiple AngularJS controllers on a single HTML page, and the page will either a, recognize only one of the controllers, or b, recognize none of the controllers.

When I comment out the content using the controller (but not the reference to the script where the controller is held,) each of the controllers seem to work totally fine and render the content as expected on the page.
When the controller(s) don't work, the area on the page is simply left blank. No {{expressions}} or any broken-looking code.

The most odd thing I've found, is that depending on which order I place the controllers will dictate which controller's content will disappear.

The controllers are NOT nested and shouldn't require each other in any way at all to function.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="AppName">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/NavController.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/TableController.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-----------First controller--------------->

<div ng-controller="NavController">
    <div class="nav">
        <p ng-repeat="link in links"><block class="button" href="{{link.URL}}" title="{{link.name}}"><a href="{{link.URL}}">{{link.name}}</a></block></p>
    </div>
</div>


<!-------Second Controller-------------------->

<div ng-controller="TableController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0">
                    <tr class="title_bar">
                        <td>Title1</td>
                        <td>Title2</td>
                        <td>Title3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color: white" ng-repeat="content in array">
            <td>{{content}}1</td>
            <td>{{content}}2</td>
            <td>{{content}}3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**NavController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('AppName', []); 

app.controller('NavController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.links = [
        {'name':'link1',
        'URL': 'link1.html'},
        {'name':'link2',
        'URL': 'link2.html'},
        {'name':'link3',
        'URL': 'link3.html'},
        {'name':'link4',
        'URL': 'link4.html'},
        {'name':'link5',
        'URL': 'link5.html'},
    ];
}]);
```

**TableController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('AppName', []); 

app.controller('TableController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.array = [
        'some stuff',
        'more stuff',
        'even more'
    ];
}]);
```

Surely Angular can run multiple controllers on one page--what is the trick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring the angular app many times, once per controller.

You should start by declaring the app, you could do that in a separate external JS file. Just make sure to include that one first, before any of the other controller JS files are included.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',....);
```

Then in each controller file, use the global app variable:

```
app.controller('NavigationController',function($scope,$location,$rootScope) ....
```

Next controller file:

```
app.controller('SomeOtherController',function($scope,$location,$rootScope) ....
```

You get the picture ....

Comment: It worked; thanks! How come I cannot declare it multiple times, though?

Comment: Basically just because that's the way javascript (and most other programming languages) work :-)  If you declare a variable and then re declare-it, you are effectively overwriting what that variable was holding in the first place.  Most languages actually disallow this altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You should be declaring you app only once:

```
var app = angular.module('AppName', []);
app.controller(...);
```

If you want to create new controllers, directives or services in the same app you should remove the dependencies array from the declaration:

```
angular
   .module('AppName')
   .controller(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the angular app many times in every controller file

You should define the app in a separate external JS file. Just make sure to include that one first, before any of the other controller JS files are included.